# Build setting for iOS in Unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, operating-system, augmented-reality

I am struggling to build a just simple AR object for iOS platform with unity and fusoria. The picture below shows my object which I want to build.

[image]

When I build this object for iOS platform, empty folder is always created without any app.
On the other hand, when I attempt to build PC, Mac & Linux standalone, it works correctly.
How can I handle with this issue ?
My unity version is 2017.2.0f3 personal and my PC is mac os.

It would be really appreciated if you answered in detail.

Comment: *"When I build this object for iOS platform, empty folder is always created without any apk file"* What? Apk is an android file not iOS. You many want to edit your question to make sense as it does not in this current form.

Comment: I am sorry for this mistake.

Comment: Are ther any errors or warnings in in the console?